# How to get the memory usage of a process in linux without root permission

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am making a site with php in a hosting server, so I don't have root permission. I have to get the max memory usage of a process which is compiled by GCC. I searched all of the possible solutions:

> `top, vmstat, ps, proc/$pid$/status, valgrind` - permission denied
>
> `pmap` - it didn't do anything

How can I get the memory usage of the process without root permission? Please give me some idea. Thanks. :)

Comment: Did You really try to read the /proc filesystem ?

Comment: Have a look at the sources to `ps` which can be found here: http://procps.sourceforge.net/ As far as I remember they are reading out `/proc/<pid>/<something>`. However you do not have a chance to read out such info if you do not own the processes in question.

Comment: @icbytes I tried to read it, but it just returned nothing or "`-bash: /proc/40914/status: Permission denied`".

Comment: @LovePaper: That's the way it is ... go and rent a root-server ... ;-)

Comment: No, did You try to read them programatically ?

Comment: @icbytes Of course, but I could read nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are really looking for-- do you want to know the amount of memory that a process is currently using? If so, then look at `/proc/<pid>/status` and examine the VmRSS line. That's the number you want (in this case, RSS means "Resident Set Size" if you're curious). That line should be parse-able in a high-level language like PHP. However, for a lower-level language like C, it should be easier to parse `/proc/<pid>/stat` which has the same values but each is separated by a space and there are no labels.

If you don't have permission to read the file, that means that the server process is running under a different user than you are logged in as. You will need to work with the hosting provider to get that resolved, or figure out how to get the server process to query its own processes (PHP script?).

Does that answer your question? Or are you interested in knowing "max memory usage" as in, "the most amount of memory that a process may use before being killed by the kernel?" This is actually something of a touchy philosophical issue for Linux. You won't find any solid information about such a maximum because there is no hard limit. Read up on "Linux memory overcommit" for more details.

Comment: If I try to take a look at `/proc/<pid>/status` or `/proc/<pid>/stat`, I always get `Permission denied` thing.

Comment: Run 'whoami' to see your username. Run 'ls -al /proc/<pid>' in order to see who owns that process. Probably a mismatch. That's why you might need to coordinate with a PHP script in order to extract the right data. The PHP script should be running with the same privileges as the troublesome process. You could pass the relevant PID to the script as a URL variable: /getVmRSS.php?pid=12345.